# polymer : command not found

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x, polymer-starter-kit

I am using ubuntu 16.04. I have install polymer-cli `npm install -g polymer-cli` which is properly installed but when I enter command `polymer server`
it is throwing error that polymer:command not found.

Comment: did you try `polymer --version`?
did you try restarting your bash?

Comment: yes it is also giving same error polymer: command not found.

Answer (score 3):

To check if a package is globally installed you can take a look at the npm root folder.

`npm root -g` will show you the root folder
`ls $(npm root -g)` therefore lists all public installed packages.

If you do not find polymer-cli there then your global installation was not successful... if you find it there but you still can not use it you probably want to try to reinstall it.

Comment: I found the polymer-cli in list name and I reinstalled for almost 2 times but still not working.

Comment: can you try to `$(npm root -g)/polymer-cli/bin/polymer.js --version` if that gives you something it's installed but node did not properly link it

Comment: Is there a way to properly link it in node?

Comment: Asking the same as @noodl_es how do you properly link polymer to node?

Comment: I'm having the same issue and that ls shows me 'npm' and 'yarn', not modules. Is my install bad (and ONLY breaking for Polymer), or is there a bad assumption perhaps in the Polymer npm module?

Answer (score 0):

For me the answer relied in the fact that the bin folder of node wasn't defined in PATH.

The fix for me was to add it to the `export PATH=` part in my `.zshrc`-file or, if you don't use ZSH, `.bash_profile`. To know what to add to this `PATH` export run `npm bin -g`. For me the output was `/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.14.0_1/bin`. After this I opened my `.zshrc`-file and added the `:/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.14.0_1/bin` to the `PATH` definition. Notice the `:` which distinguishes a new location.

`export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.14.0_1/bin"`

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If polymer-cli is globally installed successfully, change your path environment variable - add polymer.js' parent directory to it and `polymer serve` will work. You'll find polymer.js in `.npm-global/bin`